# Why is it that some software crypto wallets are restricted to certain networks only?

Tags: public-key

My basic understanding so far is that crypto wallets are nothing more than a collection of the owner/user's public keys derived from the unique seed or mnemonic using different hashing algorithms. If that is the case, are there any technical factors that restrict certain crypto wallets from generating public keys for all public networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any technical factors that restrict certain crypto wallets from generating public keys for all public networks?

Sort of.

There is an infinite amount of alternative chains, and there is an infinite amount of different mining algorithms that can be used, generally and technically speaking there is an infinite amount of different crypto-systems to be supported.

The infinite amount of crypto-systems to code support for, requires an infinitely large binary program for the wallet application.

As an infinitely large binary program is impossible, that is a technical factor that restricts every *crypto* wallets from generating public keys for every public network.

---

Now for the answer you probably really need, one can most definitely compile a binary program large enough so that almost every major *cryptocurrency* is supported. That's a very long shot, so what exchanges normally do is to build and run *parallel* "core" wallets for those many chains.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Networks as distinct cryptocurrencies**

   It is off-topic to discuss other cryptocurrencies but some wallet software that can be used for Bitcoin can also be used for other cryptocurrencies. However each cryptocurrency is different and it is often the case that even if they use some form of public-key cryptography, the specific form of keys can differ and so are usually not interchangeable. So yes, there are technical factors that make it more work to create multi-currency wallets. Arguably it would also be poor security practise to use the same seeds or private key for several currencies that have compatible keys.

   Different cryptocurrencies often have completely different network protocols and completely different technical underpinnings. For example Proof-of-Work vs Proof-of-Stake.
2. **Bitcoin networks**

   Bitcoin has several networks, mainnet, testnet and so on. I believe most Bitcoin wallets support them all.
3. **Public networks**

   I don't know of any Bitcoin implementations for any public network other than the Internet and the Internet Protocol (TCP/IP). So far as I know, most of the competing public networks are now defunct: Minitel, X25 and soon ISDN and even the venerable PSTN.